# save set preference into localstorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

So I wrote some code with a link that shows/hides a text and changes after you click it. So if you hide the text the link turns into: show text and other way around. now I need it to be saved in `webstorage` so that if you reload the page the text remains hidden or shown. I am very new to `JavaScript` and `HTML` in general.

that part of my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id='link'><a href='javascript:clo_fun()'>Always hide</a></div>
    <section class="aufgabenstellung" id="Aufgabenstellung1a">
          text
      </section>
</body>
<script>

function open_fun() {
  document.getElementById('link').innerHTML = "<a href='javascript:clo_fun()'>Always hide</a>"
  $(".aufgabenstellung").show();
}

function clo_fun() {
  document.getElementById('link').innerHTML = "<a href='javascript:open_fun()'>Always show</a>"
  $(".aufgabenstellung").hide();
}
</script>
</html>
```

My attempt looks something like this:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
 
 function Auf(open){
    localStorage.setItem('testObject', JSON.stringify("display"));
    var e = document.getElementById(open);
    e.style.display = "";
   }
 
   function Zu(close){
   localStorage.setItem('testObject', JSON.stringify("display=none"));
   var e = document.getElementById(close);
   e.style.display = "none";
  
  }
 
 function testStorage(){
     var retrievedObject = localStorage.getItem('testObject');  
     //alert(retrievedObject);
    
     if( retrievedObject == "display" ) {
     
         Auf('containerid');
      }
    }
   
testStorage();

</script>
     
  
     <a href="javascript:Auf('containerid')">Open</a>

     <a href="javascript:Zu('containerid')">Close</a>
     
      

<div id="containerid" style="display=none">
test </div>
```

I tried a bunch and do understand how `localstorage` works, but I can't seem to make it work with my code example. Like saving data with `setItem` and `getItem` doesn't seem hard but for some reason i cant make it work.

Comment: Show us your code.  What happened?

Comment: Where's your attempt for local storage? I see nothing. Reading is good for you. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: sry i edited it in, my bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing it all wrong what you should be doing is

**1)** Bind the click event to the link and then [**`toggle()`**](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) the state of the panel rather than trying to remove the anchor and add another with the onclick attribute, and when you `toggle` the panel save the state of the panel in a `localStorage` variable say `panel_state` and you will utilize a pseudo selector [**`: visible Selector`**](https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/).

**2)** On every page load, you should check if there is any variable defined in `localStorage` with the name `panel_state` if there is then you should check what state is saved and show or hide the div on the basis of the saved value.

### [**`localStorage`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

to save a variable use

```
localStorage.setItem('myCat', 'Tom');
```

to get a variable use

```
var cat = localStorage.getItem("myCat");
```

to remove the variable use

```
localStorage.removeItem("myCat");
```

Below is the basic code for you, that performs what you want you can modify it according to your needs, it will not run in the SO snippet  so I added a [**`Fiddle`**](https://jsfiddle.net/buttflattery/2tp1rrgg/4/) for you to see it working, try to hide the panel by clicking the link and then refresh the page you will see that after refresh it will still keep the panel hidden and if you again toggle the panel by clicking the link and again refresh the page it will keep the panel visible.

Change you javascript to the following

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  //get the current state 
  var panel_state = localStorage.getItem('panel_state');
  
  //check if not null
  if (panel_state !== null) {

    //check if previously saved state is visible
    if (panel_state==1) {
      //show the panel on page load
      $("#Aufgabenstellung1a").show();
    } else {
      //hide the panel on page load 
      $("#Aufgabenstellung1a").hide();
    }
  }

  $("#link").on('click', function() {
    $("#Aufgabenstellung1a").toggle();
    localStorage.setItem('panel_state', $("#Aufgabenstellung1a:visible").length);
  });

});
```

Change your `HTML` to the following

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id='link'><a href="#.">Always hide</a></div>
  <section class="aufgabenstellung" id="Aufgabenstellung1a">
    text
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, helped me a lot to get a better understanding and works perfectly.

Comment: you are welcome @ChrischKlein , don't forget to vote up and mark it as the correct answer, cheers.